# hashcat specific brute force

Tags: passwords, hash, brute-force, password-cracking, hashcat

Is this scenario possible:

I know the first three letters of the password (exact), i know the password is between 10-14 characters, i know the rest of the characters are "b,t,p,1,3,6,7" which can be repeated any number of times, and the file encrypted is a 7z file.

Is a masked attack this specific possible? i don't want to waste two months, i pratically know the password, it's just i used too many variations of it that i can't seem to open the file anymore.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a separate mask for each length, using a custom character set:

```
-1 btp1367 xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
-1 btp1367 xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
-1 btp1367 xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
-1 btp1367 xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
-1 btp1367 xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
```

... where 'xxx' is whatever the first three static characters are.

Also note that you can put these in a [mask file](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack#hashcat_mask_files):

```
btp1367,xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
btp1367,xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
btp1367,xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
btp1367,xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
btp1367,xxx?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
```

... and run them with a single hashcat invocation, supplying the maskfile filename on the commandline.

Comment: I'm getting separator unmatched using -m 11600, the hash is $7z$1$19$0$$8$b15169d712b004aa0000000000000000$4215533670$160$151$e55c0652349880299183a658f06d3203159c956edb7a9c2c695bdf6872e93c674dbce3c238e6b6977c2e11729a37365c3cc4052a8ef08323201601bbbad00c4f2847a6fc50ac01a1a80712565edf4b9fb755f55bf838c7da31d3edc9d5222a3f0e606aba8d5fd5c6fc14f60ef5d162dbb70daa4d9b3f1f0c166437491080de2343f5d45931d7e977d60465936bac0c83b3288513fb645d135b5301dfdf176e42$173$5d00100000

I searched but found no help, using an older hashcat version the error goes to line-length exception.

Comment: To test your methodology, try the hashcat example hash for your target mode: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes . If you can crack that hash (usually cracks as "hashcat"), then there's something wrong with how your hash is being extracted.